# How do I atomically rotate customer supplied encryption keys in GCS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

According to the documentation, `gsutil rewrite -k gs://my_bucket/my_folder/**` is atomic. Are there any other ways to do this (if I don't want to use the boto file)? All of the examples that do not use boto seem to be operating on individual files instead of atomically on a group of files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify, the gsutil rewrite operations are atomic **per object**, not across all objects in the matching group. There is no GCS operation that will work atomically across a group of objects (for key rotation or any other operation).